# Getting the wrong date

Tags: php, date

I am trying to fetch the date from a giant text string when a certain word is meet. So in the text field below where it says "polis", i want the date 29/7/2017

So the pattern field is the specific word I am after in this case "polis", subject is the array that contains the entire textfield.

```
22/10/2013 ånger, ska bet 6,428:-, 
bet 6428, 2109+2016+2303 inlagt
23/5/2014 bl 26/5, medd inga avgifter) 
29/7/2014 spelmissbruk 
29/7/2014 polis
29/12/2014 föreslår godkänn
27/4/2016 Föreslår godkänn
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
$subject = $row['anteckning'];
$pattern = $wordToFind;
preg_match("/$pattern/",$subject,$matchWord);
//print_r($matchWord);

if($matchWord[0] == $pattern) {
    $test1 = strstr($subject, $matchWord[0]);
    $testword = substr($test1, 0,8);
    echo $testword;                    
}
```

My problem is that i keep getting the first date 22/10/2013.

Comment: Edited my answer to only capture the dates as you requested

Answer (score 1):

```
 preg_match_all("/$pattern/",$subject,$matchWord);
```

You are using `preg_match` so get's you the first only value that finds.

Of course you will have to make some modifications to your code but you will get all the values based on `preg_match_all` function so you will handle them as you like.

Comment: ah so i need to break it up in lines first.

Comment: That would be wise if you want the dates. But if you break it into lines you will be able to use preg_match per line as well cause there is 1 date per line.

Comment: mabye something like this foreach(preg_split("/((\r?\n)|(\r\n?))/", $subject) as $line){
    // do stuff with $line
}

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.*` as a wildcard on each side of the string in preg_match_all to capture all in one.

I use `i` to make it case insensitive to make sure it captures `polis, Polis, POLIS` and so on.

EDIT: I see now you only want the dates. Added a capture of the dates to the regex.
$matches[1] will hold the dates only and $matches[0] will hold the complete line.

```
preg_match_all('/(\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}).*polis.*/i', $str, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

output: (my example)

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(15) "29/7/2014 polis"
    [1]=>
    string(15) "28/4/2016 POLIS"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(9) "29/7/2014"
    [1]=>
    string(9) "28/4/2016"
  }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/Bo7ON

Comment: @SixxsterNameDawg I see that you have not yet taken the tour of SO. When you complete the tour you will earn your first badge. https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: I will do that!